# Angular Routing: How to apply customization to the array passed to RouterModule.forRoot

Tags: angular, routes

Instead of passing a static array to RouterModule.forRoot, I would like to pass a class (or function) that returns an array of routes based on the user's permissions and organization.

The challenge for me has been injecting service references into the customized router class. The other challenge has been to ensure that the class gets invoked even when the user refreshes the browser.

Substitution for the standard RouterModule reference.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouterModule, useClass: CustomRouter }],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The custom router:

```
    class CustomRouter implements OnInit {

      constructor(
        private authService: AuthService) {
        }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.build();
      }

      build(): void {
        const routes: Routes = [];

      // Logic for determining the appropriate user-based routes.

        RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
      }
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for ChildrenOutletContexts!
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Another way to approach this is to use a Guard to guard specific routes based on user permissions.

Comment: A guard would not work in this use-case because the route will vary by user. That's why I'm trying to implement dynamic routes.